# How can I draw a slope line y=m*x+C using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, math

I want to plot different points and show the data in a chart in jQuery. If slope lines can be drawn using jQuery then it will be easier to draw chart. Is there any way to draw slopes in jQuery?

Comment: http://processingjs.org/, http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery is just a library that smooths over some annoying parts of javascript, so it doesn't have built in drawing tools.

I'd recommend looking at canvas - it's an HTML5 element that allows you to draw anything on it. [A decent tutorial can be found at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes).

If you are looking to draw graphs, I'd recommend looking at something like [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) - they've already solved this problem!